# how to get vimdiff apply both REMOTE and LOCAL changes?

Tags: vimdiff, mergetool

when resolving a git conflict using vimdiff is it possible to apply changes from both buffers ? i tried

```
:diffget RE LO
```

and hoped that it would apply the changes in that order, so

```
<some content>
<REMOTE>
<LOCAL>
<rest of the file>
```

but it failed:

```
E94: No matching buffer for RE LO
```

Comment: This is probably more of a question for vim.stackexchange.com, but the answer seems obvious: apparently `diffget` takes the name of *one* buffer as its (lone) argument, so `RE LO` is the buffer named "RE LO", not the *two* buffers "RE" and "LO" in that order. You'll therefore presumably need two separate `diffget` calls.

Comment: hmmm, but when i call `diffget RE` it wil put RE content into MERGED, but then when i call `diffget LO` it will put LO into MERGED - but not appand into existing MERGE content

Comment: Probably, then, you want something other than `diffget`. As I don't use vimdiff, I'm not familiar with its commands. There is a lot over on the vi/vim site (which I apparently spelled slightly wrong): see, e.g., https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/git-mergetool-vimdiff-command